# Java MessageFormat cannot format

Tags: java, kotlin

Here is a string `template` read from file.

```
Dialogue: {0}
Dialogue: {1}
```

After I read it from file, I want to format this string using given array.

```
var sentences = arrayOf("hello", "world")
var template = File("file_path").readText()

template = MessageFormat.format(template, sentences)

print(template)
```

But I get output.

```
Dialogue: [Ljava.lang.String;@27c170f0
Dialogue: {1}
```

## EDIT

If I put array elements one by one, I will get right output.

Comment: Because `MessageFormat.format` accept `Object...` and see `sentences` as one `Object` not an array of `Object`. In Kotlin not sure what to do... In Java it would be as simple as declaring `sentences` as an array.

Comment: Also, you need to assign the result of MessageFormat.format() to a variable and print that result. The code you posted can't produce the output you gave.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your remaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sentence` variable is an array and not multiple argument. You have to to put a `*` ([spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)) before to transform it into vararg.

```
MessageFormat.format(template, *sentences)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) `*`:

```
MessageFormat.format(template, *sentences)
```

It will transform an array into vararg to match [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method signature:

```
format(String pattern, Object... arguments)
```

From the docs:

> When we call a vararg-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g.
>   asList(1, 2, 3), or, if we already have an array and want to pass its
>   contents to the function, we use the spread operator (prefix the array
>   with *)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not know which answer should be accepted.You are both right.

Comment: @Lionel Briand answered a few seconds earlier, so it will be honest to accept his one :)